# Split contents of file into Array[String] in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, split, file-read

I have a SQL file that contains several queries. Since it is a SQL file, it has queries delimited with semicolon (;). I want to read the SQL file and have the queries as an `Array[String]` in Scala.

For example, I have `queries.sql` file that contains queries like:

```
select * from table1;
select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where col1 = ''
col2 = '';
select count(*) from table;
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Array("select * from table1","select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where col1 = '' col2 =' '","select count(*) from table")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
import scala.io.Source
val theArrayYouWant = Source.fromFile(<filename>).getLines.mkString.split(";")
```

Comment: Where you have to replace `<filename>` with something like `"yourfile.sql"`

Comment: Thank you ,that was super quick :) ,and it gives me exactly what I want .Thank you